# What does the treasury yield mean that is causing the market pullback?

Tags: stocks, bonds

Does the treasury yield mean current yield or yield to maturity according to [Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/rates-bonds/government-bonds/us)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "yield" quoted for government bonds is always Yield to Maturity - never current yield.

For corporate bonds (which you didn't ask about) - other measures of yield can be quoted, such as Yield To Worst for callable bonds, meaning what's the worst possible yield I can get if I hold the bond until it matures or is called (whichever comes first).